# Проверить на заполненность

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как одним условием проверить на заполненность все поля ввода?

```
        var name = $("input[name=name]").val();
        var tel = $("input[name=tel]").val();
        var adress1 = $("input[name=adress1]").val();
        var adress2 = $("input[name=adress2]").val();
```

Comment: Добавить всем инпутам атрибут `required`, и проверять либо вызовом метода `checkValidity` (предпочтительно), либо сравнением количества элементов выбранных по селектору с псевдоклассом `:invalid`. А таскать каждый value в переменную и ее значение проверять - это, пардон, глупейший из возможных вариантов (имеет смысл только если нужна поддержка совсем старых-мертвых браузеров, типа IE9-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ([name,tel,adress1,adress2].includes('')) {
  // has empty values
}
```

или

```
if (['',name,tel,adress1,adress2,''].join(',').includes(',,')) {
  // has empty values
}
```

или как нормальные люди

```
if (name == '' || tel == '' || address1 == '' || address2 == '') {
  // has empty values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот если именно поля ввода:

```js
let $inputs = $('#form input');
  
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  let flag = true;
  $inputs.css('color', 'initial');
  $inputs.each(function(idx, el) {
    if (!$(el).val()) {
      $(el).css('color', 'red');
      flag = false;
    }
  })
  if (flag) {
    console.log('no empty - next action');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"/>
  <input type="text" name="tel" placeholder="tel"/>
  <input type="text" name="adress1" placeholder="adress1"/>
  <input type="text" name="adress2" placeholder="adress2"/>
</form>
<input type=button id="btn" value="do some"/>
```